GLMs and their conditional expectation and variance
Let the density of the distribution of response $y_i | x_i$ in GLMs denote as:
$$f(y; \theta, \phi) = \exp\left(\frac{y\theta - b(\theta)}{\phi} + c(y; \phi)\right)$$
Then conditional expectation and variance are given as: $E[y_i | x_i] = \mu_i = b'(\theta_i)$ and $\text{Var}[y_i | x_i] = \phi \cdot b''(\theta_i)$. Furthermore the variance function is given as $V[\mu] = b''(\theta(\mu))$.
I checked with Poisson and Bernoulli distribution and it really seems to hold. But I am puzzled on where those derivatives are coming from and why that should hold?
Any input is welcome!

One approach would be to first find the moment generating function of of $Y$, that is $M(t)=E(e^{tY})$.  You can then derive these results via the cumulant generating function of $Y$ (equal to the log of $M(t)$).

I have always wondered about this myself as well. There are proofs for it like using the score in the other answer, or the moment generating function like mentioned in the comments. But they are indirect and it is not directly intuitive that the expectation value equals the derivative of the log normalisation factor $b(\theta)$. I hope that this post may help a bit to see more directly why the mean and variance are related to the normalisation factor.
Preliminary definitions
We can simplifying the question with $\phi = 1$ (without loss of generality). Then
$$f(y; \theta) \propto e^{\theta y} h(y)$$
or with a normalisation factor
$$f(y; \theta)  = \frac{ e^{\theta y} h(y)}{\int_{\forall y} e^{\theta y} h(y) \, \text{d}y} = \frac{ e^{\theta y} h(y)}{z(\theta)}  $$
where $z(\theta) = e^{b(\theta)}$ and $h(y) = e^{c(y)}$ are the normalisation and base measure but taken outside of the exponential function. Also note that this base measure $h$ is in fact the same as the unnormalized density when $\theta = 0$, (then the exponential factor equals 1, $e^{0y} = 1$ for all values $y$).

Intuitive viewpoint
This factor $e^{\theta y}$ can be regarded as some energy/temperature term as in the Boltzmann distribution. If $\theta$ is larger then larger values $y$ will become relatively more probable.
For example, in terms of the odds ratios, these scale with a factor $e^{\theta (y_1-y_2)}$
$$\frac{f(y_1;\theta)}{f(y_2;\theta)} = \frac{f(y_1;0)}{f(y_2;0)} e^{\theta (y_1-y_2)}$$
The graph below might show this more intuitively

The image uses three different truncated exponential distributions (different shades) with different domains, [-2.5, -1.5], [0, 1] and [6,7].
The effect of the term $e^{\theta y}$ is shown in the second image. It can be seen that this changes the area of the function and the amount of change depends on the values $y$. If we increase $\theta$ then at negative densities the area decreases, at positive values the area increases. The decrease/increase is stronger the further away we are from zero.
So in a way, the change of the area as we change the parameter $\theta$ is related to where the probability density is distributed. So that is why the normalisation factor $z(\theta)$ or it's logarithm $b(\theta)$ is related to the mean (and the variance).

Exact computation
The constant of proportionality is found by integrating (or summing) over the range of the variable $Y$
$$e^{b(\theta)} = z(\theta) = \int_{\Omega_Y} e^{\theta y} h(y) dy$$
and by differentiation under the integration sign
$$\begin{array}{rcl}
z'(\theta) &=& \int_{\Omega_Y} y e^{\theta y} h(y) dy\\
z''(\theta) &=& \int_{\Omega_Y} y^2 e^{\theta y} h(y) dy
\end{array}$$
With the above three functions we can express the mean and variance.
$$\begin{array}{rcl}
E[y] &=& \frac{\int_{\Omega_Y} y e^{\theta y} h(y) dy}{\int_{\Omega_Y}  e^{\theta y} h(y) dy} \\ &=& 
 \frac{z'(\theta)}{z(\theta)}\\
& =& \left[\log \, z(\theta)\right]'\\
& =& b(\theta)'
\\ \phantom{1} \\
\text{Var}[y] &=& \frac{\int_{\Omega_Y} y^2 e^{\theta y} h(y) dy}{\int_{\Omega_Y}  e^{\theta y} h(y) dy} - \left(  \frac{\int_{\Omega_Y} y e^{\theta y} h(y) dy}{\int_{\Omega_Y}  e^{\theta y} h(y) dy} \right)^2 \\ &=& \ \frac{z''(\theta)}{z(\theta)} 
- \left( \frac{z'(\theta)}{z(\theta)} \right)^2\\
& =& \left[\log \, z(\theta)\right]''\\
& =& b(\theta)''
\end{array}$$

You have to keep in mind that $Y_i, $ the responses, follow exponential family of distributions. Then we can get our required formula working with the log-likelihood of $\theta, ~\ell(\theta)$ and its score $\partial_\theta\ell:$
$$\begin{align}\ell(\theta)&=\frac{y\theta-b(\theta)}{\phi}+c(y;\phi)\\{\partial_\theta\ell}&=\frac{y-b^\prime(\theta)}{\phi};\end{align}$$
for the expression of expectation, use the fact that $\mathbf E[\partial_\theta\ell]=0$ and for that of variance, use $\mathbf E[\partial_\theta^2\ell]=-\mathbf E[(\partial_\theta\ell)^2].$
--
Reference:
$\rm[I]$ Generalized Additive Models: An Introduction with R, Simon N. Wood, CRC, $2017, $ sec. $3.1.1.$
